# Wifi issues with fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, kernel, 22.04

I made a fresh installation of Ubuntu on my laptop. At the first, the wifi was working pretty well. But then it started misbehaving. Taking a long time to connect wifi and after like 10-20 seconds of connectivity, it disconnects automatically.
I tried some solutions posted here such as disabling ipv6, although that allowed the wifi to connect, the connectivity was zero.

I was using kernel 5.15 which I then upgraded to 6.0.1, but nothing is working
except for the wired connection which is superfast.

Any solutions please

Comment: Obvious thing to check - are you sure it’s not a problem with the WiFi? Worth checking from another computer / mobile phone. Apologies if I’m stating the obvious and you’ve already tried this.

Comment: The mobile hotspot used to work just fine. Now it doesn't even detect one. The other devices are connected to wifi and are working perfectly.